# calculate difference in HH:mm between two different time in same date with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two date fields with different time - `INIT1` and `END1`. I need to populate a third field `TTL1` with the difference in `hours` and `minutes` between these two date fields.

Then I have two other date fields with different time - `INIT2` and `END2` and I have to do the same thing with these. In the end I have to add the two differences, one of which could be `zero`, to get the total time in `hours` and `minutes`. I've tried several solutions with the examples found here, but they don't fulfill my need.

I am a newbie, be understanding, please...Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected input and output?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already know the library "date-fns"? I think it can be useful for this case. I'm almost sure that this link can be the solution for your question.

https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/differenceInMinutes

(also, they have options for difference in seconds, hours, days and etc).